# MySQL RegEx search each column

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search

I'm searching my **MySQL** Database with **Regex** like this:

`$search` looks like this `WORD1|WORD2|WORD3`

```
$regexp = "REGEXP '[[:<:]][[:alpha:]]*($search)[[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]'";

SELECT * FROM
    zitate
WHERE
    UPPER(`field1`) $regexp OR UPPER(`field2`) $regexp OR UPPER(`field3`)
```

Now I'm getting, as expected, every entry where **$search matches field1 or field2 or field3**

But I only want to recieve the entries where WORD1, WORD2 and WORD3 **match within each column**, not within the whole table.

I know this is because of the `OR` in my query but is there something better than writing something like this:

```
WHERE
    UPPER(`field1`) $regexp AND UPPER(`field2`) $regexp
OR
    UPPER(`field2`) $regexp AND UPPER(`field3`) $regexp
OR
    UPPER(`field1`) $regexp AND UPPER(`field3`) $regexp
OR
    UPPER(`field1`) $regexp AND UPPER(`field2`) $regexp AND UPPER(`field3`) $regexp
```

Or should I use this `AND`, `OR` query?

Thanks for any tips and answers!

Comment: Really nobody who can give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: in MySQL logical values are actually maps to `0` and `1`, so instead of `OR`ing them, you could simply add them like:

```
WHERE 1 < UPPER(`field1`) $regexp
        + UPPER(`field2`) $regexp
        + UPPER(`field3`) $regexp
```

Alternatively, you should learn about MySQL's full text indexing/searching features, or find some other solution, like [Fulltext Search with InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381186/fulltext-search-with-innodb) .