# Soundex search doen't give correct results

Tags: mysql, soundex

I've got a table product and the user needs to be able to search through products using an autocomplete function on a text field. 
But I want also when people make little mistakes in the name, it gets found aswell.

**What is needed**

All my titles are formated like this: [brand] [productnamename] [versionname]
So for example, I've got a product 'foo evo HD3455' i need to find it when i type 'foo' or 'evo' or 'HD2455' or parts of it, but also when they type 'froo eno HD3455' for example they need to find it aswell

**What i have**

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE SOUNDEX(title) LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX('here the search text'),2),'%')
```

**Whats not working**

It works for the brands, even if you make a little mistake in the name, but when I search for the [productname] or [versionname], then it does't work. When i type the [brand] first and then the [versionname] the results with the [versionname] in it don't show up.

**Where i need it for**

I'm going to use it for an autocomplete field, so that users can easily find products, even if they make a mistake in their search text.

*I can't use fulltext search because i use innoDB*

Comment: `soundex()` isn't particularly useful.  What you probably want is Levenshtein distance, a very clever method (described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).  If you Google for Levenshtein and MySQL, I'm sure you'll stumble upon an implementation in the datbase.

Comment: "I can't use fulltext search because i use innoDB" I don't understand this statement.

Comment: @Strawberry innoDB doen't support fulltext search (read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381186/fulltext-search-with-innodb)

Comment: InnoDB supports FULLTEXT at MySQL 5.6 and above - check the manual at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html

Comment: @DMac i have 5.5.13 so its not suported

Comment: 5.6 has been around since 2011. Maybe it's time to upgrade!